# Session variables disable Heroku deployment (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, deployment, heroku

I'm desperate now, searched a lot, but nothing helped.
I have rails 3.1.0
My small app is just table with data and sorting filtering stuff.
I worked perfect on Heroku, but then I added a little bit of session variables to store filtering parameters through pages. It works perfect on localhost, but Heroku shows "We're sorry, but something went wrong".
I tried do it with --stack cedar - doesn't help
Heroku logs doesn't say anything useful.

Again I say - if I will delete all sessions It works perfect. :(
Here is my code where I use sessions, I don't see anything heroku-killing here, just regular sessions:

```
def index
@all_ratings=Movie.vasta
@selected_ratings=[]
#if !session[:ratings].nil?
##  redirect_to 'movies_path'
#end
if !params[:sort].nil?
  session[:sr]=params[:sort]
end
if !params[:ratings].nil?
  params[:ratings].each_key do |key|
    @selected_ratings << key
  end
elsif
  @selected_ratings = session[:selre]
end
session[:selre]=@selected_ratings
@movies = Movie.order(session[:sr]).where("rating IN (?)", session[:selre])

@varka=session[:sr]
```

end

Thank you very much in advance.

log

2013-08-01T18:34:24.021832+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/movies host=myassnevercries.herokuapp.com fwd="88.85.159.248" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=673ms status=500 bytes=728

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: Looks like you'd end up trying to order by nil if there was no sort parameter and there was no previous value in the session

Comment: But sort by nil means that I just don't sort. It works with params[:sort] when it is nil, why doesn't it works with session of the same thing?

Comment: I doubt the order method is expecting you to pass nil.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's confusing, but if I make code without sessions and go there without defining :sort it will run ok even on heroku. In my case I just changed params[:sort] to session[:sr], that's all... Anyway, I want to try to find info still, hope I will get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same database locally as you are on Heroku? If not, I'd suggest turning on SQL logging and seeing what the generated SQL is. I'd guess the problem is nil in order or where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this go into an infinite redirect if you define `session[:ratings]`?

BTW, I find `if !variable.nil?` really confusing. You can just use `if variable` or `if variable.present?` which reads better.

Anyhow, if `session[:ratings]` is defined once, it'll redirect to the index action again, and it'll reach `if !session[:ratings].nil?` and it's still not nil and redirect again. I don't see how this could work locally. Aren't you getting some kind of infinite redirect error from your browser? The session variables don't get reset or cleared on redirect.

Comment: Indeed even `unless variable.nil?` is a better way to write that, but the two you listed make much more sense.

Comment: session[:ratings] and redirect are in comments, they are not executed, I have no redirections here at all.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the lines commented out were the ones causing the problem.